# Import.meta.env undefined vite/react

Tags: reactjs, vite, .env

I am using vitejs to compile my react app however after build .env imports become undefined.

```
// .env
VITE_BASE_URL=http://localhost:5000
```

```
// Login.jsx
const BASE_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL;

const Login = () => {
    console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_BASE_URL);

return (<>Login Page<>)
}
```

Am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: make sure your `.env` was loaded when you build your app, enable debugging when building and start from there

Comment: This is the way to use environment variables in Vite. In that case I'd reckon to provide the `vite.config.ts` file (whatever your config file name is) and provide the command you run to run your Vite application